# ASP.NET PhysicalFileProvider not available in Startup.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, nuget, owin

I am trying to serve static files in a ASP.NET 4.6 web application, MVC 5.2.3 using the Entity Framework. I'm following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files) tutorial.

I'm getting a compiler error:

> The type or namespace name 'PhysicalFileProvider' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

It seems that the using `Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders` is not actually being used (it is grayed out in Visual Studio.

I have tried importing various assemblies without any luck. I'm not a .NET developer and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Monica.Startup))]

namespace Monica
{
    public partial class Startup
    {

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseStaticFiles(); // For the wwwroot folder

            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                    Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"MyStaticFiles")),
                RequestPath = new PathString("/StaticFiles")
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should install the nugget package:

> Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical

Right click the project -> Manage Nugget Packages -> Browse -> Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical -> Install.

The using statement should be available to you afterwards.

Comment: That worked, thank you. I had to install the package using the NuGet Package Manager Console. It seems that particular package does not list it's supported frameworks in the gallery and hence the install option was not available.

Comment: For .Net core, this works:  dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical --version 3.1.0